# Why isn't [0,1] an open set by this definition of Ross

Tags: general-topology

Defintion : Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space. Let $E$ be a subset of $S$. An element $s_0 \in E$ is interior to $E$ if for some $r > 0$ we have
$\{s \in S : d(s,s_0) < r\} \subseteq E$.
We write $E^\circ$ for the set of points in $E$ that are interior to $E$. The
set $E$ is open in $S$ if every point in $E$ is interior to $E$, i.e., if $E = E^\circ$.

By definition , I can make my $r$ very large, say $r=1000$ and have every point in $[0,1]$ has to have a distance of less than $1000$, so every point in my set is interior , thus $[0,1]$ is indeed an open set, but the textbook says that $[0,1]$ is a closed set. Could someone point out why my definition is wrong?

Pardon my English, it is my second language, if anything is unclear I can clarify it.

Comment: What you've shown is that $E = [0,1] \subset \{s\in S : d(s,s_0) < 1000 \} $ , but the definition needs to have it the other way around.

Comment: in the title, you mean $[0,1]$, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes sir

Comment: @NinadMunshi but isn't the set of E up to me?

Comment: @JosephRock: No. $E$ is a specific subset of $S$, and the question is whether **that specific set** is open in $S$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But in this case E=[0,1] and I do indeed have an r that satisfies my defintion in the question right? namely r=1000

Comment: @JosephRock: No, you do not: you have misunderstood the requirement for a point to be in the interior of $[0,1]$. In order for $1$ to be in the interior of $[0,1]$, there must be an $r>0$ such every real number that is less than $r$ away from $1$ is inside $[0,1]$. But there is no such $r$: no matter what $r>0$ you pick, the point $1+\frac{r}2$ is less than $r$ away from $1$ and **not** inside $[0,1]$. You have $E\subseteq\{s\in S:d(s,s_0)<r\}$, when for $s_0$ to be in the interior of $E$ the inclusion has to go the other way.

Comment: thanks for your reply sir, but one fine point that you said , " every real number that is less than r away from 1 is inside [0,1]"  However here isn't the definition only looking at points in the set S where set S is [0.1]? So even if there is a point 1.01 that is less than r away from 1, I do not need to look at it since it is out of the set S.

Comment: @JosephRock: No, it’s taking the space $S$ to be $\Bbb R$, the whole real line. It is true, however, that if we ask whether $[0,1]$ is open in the space $[0,1]$, instead of in the space $\Bbb R$, then the answer is *yes*: every space is an open subset of itself.

Comment: @JosephRock Ahhhh, Brian beat me to the comment. Yes Joseph, if you take $(S, d) = ([0,1], |\cdot |)$ (where $|\cdot |$ denotes the usual Euclidean metric), and also $$E = S = [0,1]$$ then yes, every point inside $[0,1]$, including $0$ and $1$, is considered an interior point, because technically "there is nothing else." I believe most of us here assumed you took $(S, d) = (\mathbb{R}, |\cdot |)$ and $E=[0,1]$, which is where there are issues about the size of your open balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote
$$B_\epsilon(s_0) = \{s \in S \ | \ d(s,s_0) < r\}.$$ These are called *open balls*, and to be a point in the interior of a subset $E$ in a space $S$ with a metric (or generally any topological space) there must exist an open neighborhood $U$ containing that point *that is wholy contained within the subset* $E$. In the context of this example, there must exist some $\epsilon >0$ such that $U=B_\epsilon(s_0) \subseteq E$. Note in the example you gave with $\epsilon = 1000$, the open ball fails to be contained within the set $[0,1]$.

Intuitively, you should think about points in the interior of the set $E$ as having "room around them," which is what this definition is precisely trying to say. You say that $s_0 \in E$ is in the interior if $s_0$ has some wiggle room:

[image]

But in contrast, if we considered some $s_0$ on the *boundary*, i.e. the black border above (or, in the case of $E = [0,1]$, the points $0$ or $1$), observe that they *don't* have any wiggle room! You can't find any $\epsilon > 0$ such that you can fit $B_\epsilon(s_0)$ inside $E$.

This is all considering that $E \neq S$! In other words, $(S,d) = (\mathbb{R},|\cdot |)$.

Comment: why does the open ball fail to be within the set?

Comment: @JosephRock Let's consider some arbitrary point in $[0,1]$, say $\frac12$. Then the open ball you defined, $B_{1000}(\frac12)$, even centered in the very middle of this interval, still goes *outside* the interval, since for instance, $d(\frac{1}{2},50)<1000$, yet $50 \not\in [0,1]$. I am assuming here we are using the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: but can't I find some r that satisfies my defintion in the question since I am allowed to pick any r >0?

Comment: @JosephRock Well the thing is, $[0,1]$, in the metric space $\mathbb{R}$, is a closed set, so you can't surround *every* point with an open ball. The interior of of it though is $(0,1)$, and you can do such a task there.

Comment: I have a question on how you define open ball, why is it that we must care about points to the right of the interval of [0,1] when any point after 1, such as 1.000001 is not considered since 1.000001 is not in set S?

Comment: @JosephRock But it is considered in the definition of interior! The definition says that you *must have* that $B_\epsilon (s_0) \subseteq E$. If there is an element of $B_\epsilon (s_0)$ that is not in $E$, then this condition is not satisfied!

Comment: Thanks for your edited and detailled response. I mean we defined s ∈ S, so we are only considering elements that are within [0,1]? BUt here it seems like we are considering points such as 1.0001

Comment: @JosephRock Please see my response to your question above (below Brian) which should clear up some confusion!

Comment: Hi Andrew, so (0,1) is not an open set here right? Because if I have r=1000, then there exist no real number that is within (0,1) as the ball has only maximum r= 1?

Comment: @JosephRock If your space is $[0,1]$ with the induced metric topology, then $(0,1)$ is an open set since its interior is itself. But I'm not sure this answers your question -- could you try rewording it?

Comment: I sort of understand the defintion using the ball definition that you defined, however using Ross's defintion of interior points ; An element 0∈ is interior to  if for some >0  {∈:(,0)<}⊆. However in a metric space of R, in the set [0,1], I can find a value such as 0.99 which is within the "ball" on the left hand and this satisfies the definition as the definition only requires me to have some S that d(s,s0)<r, however it didn't say that I must have the distance from the left or right... So by this definition I am able to construct an open set for [0,1]?

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained why the proof you propose is wrong. There are still a few misconceptions in your post that I think are worth clearing up.

First is the notion of what an open set is. The definition you wrote is completely correct, but saying "$[0, 1]$ is an open set" is, to be pedantic, unclear. Being open is not a property of a set, it's a property of a subset of a topological space (in this case, lets just say of a metric space). It is not an absolute notion, but a relative one. Indeed, $([0, 1], |\cdot|)$ is itself a metric space, so $[0, 1]$ is an open subset of this metric space. However, it is not an open subset of the metric space $(\mathbb R, |\cdot|)$.

Also, that $[0, 1]$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ is not a priori enough to conclude that it is not open. Although it is true (by connectedness) that proper nonempty closed subsets of $\mathbb R$ are not open, this is not a general fact about metric spaces. Being closed and being open are not mutually exclusive possibilities. For example, take $(0, 1) \cup (2, 3)$ with the restriction of the Euclidean metric. Then both subsets $(0, 1)$ and $(2, 3)$ are open, so $(0, 1)$ is both open and closed in this space.

Comment: So being an open set is a property of subset is what you are saying?